# How does one build a door motion sensor project with Arduino Uno board to send alerts to an Android Phone?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, android

1. What are the materials I will need for the project? We want the project to work like this: When the door is opened, we get an alert to our Android Phone.
2. What is the circuit structure going to look like?
3. Which is simpler, GPRS, Bluetooth or Wifi to get the alert?
4. What is the best IDE to work on for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I could comment on this, I would say that this question really sounds like you haven't actually done any research to look into a solution.

But, in simple terms:

1. Arduino Uno, Android phone, GSM shield, contact sensor or limit switch
2. The sensor or switch needs to be connected to an I/O pin on the Arduino, and will probably need to be connected to 5V.
3. GSM(GPRS) is going to provide the most mobility
4. Arduino